# How can specifiy to load plugin.properties as UTF-8 encoding file into Eclipse RCP Neon

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I try to found a solution to launch Eclipse RCP (*version Neon : 4.6*) and it's loading all my **"plugin.properties"** file which are encoding in UTF-8.
In fact, Eclipse Neon open my file like an ANSI file so I have encoding trouble.

If I use Eclipse RCP (*version Juno : 3.8*), it was able to load my **"plugin.properties"** file like UTF-8 encoding file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The plugin.properties file must use ISO-8859-1 encoding.

You can encode Unicode chars in the properties file using the `\uNNNN` style (for example `\u2009` for the 'thin space' character).

Comment: Can you explain why it's not possible under eclipse neon 4.6 and not under Juno 3.8?!

Comment: I don't think it was ever possible. What were you doing in 3.8?

Comment: Under 3.8, my plugin.properties file was loaded as UTF-8 file.
In fact, when I show message provided from my plugin.properties, those messages were well encoded under my plugins but not under "Installation details".

Comment: Note that you may be able to get the properties editor to use UTF-8 encoding but I don't know of any way to get the Eclipse/OSGi plug-in code to use anything other than the default ISO-8859-1 encoding.